# JAR Creation Failed in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am using Eclipse Indigo, Jdk and Jre 1.8.
I have errors when creating JAR files like this :

Exported with compile errors: `comX/com/abc/component/ext/common/StringUtil.java`

Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: `comX/com/abc/component/logging/AsLog$QItem.java`

At `StringUtil.java` I checked there are 2 imports that not resolved

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

--> Still don't know what the solution

And I already make sure that this file is exist: `comX/com/abc/component/logging/AsLog$QItem.java`

I already Clean and Build Project, but the errors is still.

[Here is the JAR File Specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcQTW.png)
And I check for this option in JAR Manifest Specification : **Use existing manifest from workspace**.

Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you.

-xtin-

Comment: Note that Eclipse Indigo is now 9 years and 15 releases old

Comment: I already tried using Eclipse Luna and the errors are a lot, included these 2 errors too :D

Comment: Eclipse Luna is still 6 years and 12 releases old, Eclipse 2020-06 is the current release. However changes release is not likely to fix this problem, but there isn't enough information here to know what the problem is.

Comment: I already add this post with JAR File Spec Screenshot, I hope the information is enough to know the problem.